# htaccess send 404 status on multiple 404 redirects

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rules in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en-us/
Rewriterule ^(.*) /en-us/error-404/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewriterule ^(.*) /error-404/ [L]
```

And it's working fine. When there are requests starts with `/en-us/`, I can see the content of `/en-us/error-404/` page and in all other cases I see the content of `/error-404/` page. However, the status code received from the server is `200 OK`.

Is it possible to send `404 Not Found` in both cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`if/elseif/else` conditions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#else) to use different `ErrorDocument` directives: (available in `Apache 2.4+`)

```bash
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/en-us/#">
   ErrorDocument 404 /en-us/error-404/
</If>
<Else>
   ErrorDocument 404 /error-404/
</Else>
```

Comment: What if I would need three variations?

Comment: It was covered in documentation link I shared. There is a [`ElseIf` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#elseif)

Comment: It did. Please mention Apache 2.4.26+ requirement for this. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks good point, edited in answer.

Comment: @VladStratulat Apache 2.4.26 is only required if using _nested_ conditions, not when simply using `<ElseIf>`. From Apache 2.4.13, expression syntax can be used directly in the `ErrorDocument` itself, so you might be able to avoid the If-Else construct altogether if there is a _pattern_.